# use the bathroom as a changing room

Tags: halacha, minhag, clothing, tznius-modesty

from [shulchan aruch orach chaim 2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x342) mishna brura there

and [shulchan aruch orach chaim 239.2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1064)

(davka feldheim translation

2: THE LAW REGARDING PUTTING ON CLOTHES
mishna berura
1. "...For this reason, one must likewise take care always, when not compelled /to do otherwise/, to avoid exposing even a little of any of his flesh which is normally kept covered by clothing all the time..." 
2. "I.e., when he gets up and emerges from underneath the covering of his sheet, where he was lying naked after having removed his undershirt..."

239: THE LAW WITH RESPECT TO /THE READING OF/ KERIAS SHEMA BEFORE /GOING TO/ BED
2 When one takes off his undershirt, he should not turn it around /at the bottom and lift it/ upwards from below, since if /he does/ so his body will become naked. Instead, he should slide it off over his head, /after/ having covered himself underneath /the undershirt/ with his bedclothes /beforehand/, and /thus/ get into bed.)

it seems that what is normally kept covered by clothing should not be unclothed unless no choice
and that a sheet is considered covered (clothed)

if i want to change my clothing during the day

**can i use a bathroom as a covering wile i change my clothing? or do i need to go under a sheet?**

{edit} **can i use a [Portable Changing Room](http://thetanningstore.com/images/products/10029.png)? dose it also need to [cover on top](http://www.thelashop.com/images/P/01ROM001-DC-1900.jpg)?**

PS i understand about AYLOR but i am looking for sources

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31853/getting-dressed-in-the-bathroom?rq=1

Comment: @hazoriz Sorry, no sources, but I've definitely learned you can change the simple way if you're in the bathroom

Answer (score 5):

I heard from Rabbi *Yisrael* Reisman (Brooklyn, New York) that, although one may not be exposed in general, he may in a bathhouse, and our bathrooms with showers or bathtubs count, so one can undress in a bathroom that has a shower or bathtub. My memory may misserve me, of course, and you should consult your rabbi for a practical ruling in any event.

Comment: I've heard a similar ruling from a few rabbanim but they pointed out that isn't so clear cut being that in order to qualify as a bathhouse it would need to be a room which it's completely dedicated for a bath which would make being naked the norm for that room. Our bathrooms have toilets and sinks so they serve other purposes.

Comment: @msh210 mishna berrura 2.1 it says ".../This ruling does/ not /apply/ when one cannot act otherwise. Similarly, /when one is/ in a bathhouse, where it is normal for people to go naked and one cannot act otherwise, it is not /considered/ indecent /if one exposes himself there/. When one baths in a river the same ruling applies, except that one must be careful to undress and dress as close to the river as possible, so that he will not go unnecessarily with his body exposed..." it seams that it can only be done if no other choice, but in the case of the question there is a choice to use a sheet

Comment: @shmuel, I know what I was taught. Perhaps it's not in agreement with the _MB_, relying on other views: I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Rabbi Moseh Feinstein z”l, in [Shut Igros Moshe (YD III,47:3)](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=920&st=&pgnum=285), and Rabbi Binyamin Zilber, in [Shut Az Nidberu (8:50)](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=881&pgnum=122), both posit that since a bathroom is a place dedicated for being in a state of undress, therefore one can change clothing there without covering themselves, even when not bathing.

However, others, such as Rabbi Chaim Kanyevsky (Da’as Noteh, Vol. 1, Levishas Ha'begadim, 106) takes a more stringent view, that if the person only went to the bathroom to change, that would not be enough of a reason to permit being immodest there.