# Speaking as you enter a bathroom?

Tags: speech-talking, shulchan-aruch, bathroom

Shulchan Aruch Orach Chayim, Siman 3, Seif 1 says;
 כְּשֶׁיִּכָּנֵס לְבֵית הַכִּסֵא יֹאמְרוּ הִתְכַּבְּדוּ מְכֻבָּדִים וְכו'. 
וְעַכְשָׁו לֹא נָהֲגוּ לְאָמְרוֹ

When one enters into the throne room (bathroom stall), say: "התכבדו מכובדים, etc." But now we are not habituated to recite it.

What is the full phrase? Where is it from? What does it mean? Why don't we say it anymore? And should we say it? I thought we weren't allowed to speak in a bathroom.

Comment: maybe you say it right before you enter.

Comment: In this context it doesn't mean 'throne', just as in the context of  a table it doesn't mean 'throne'.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17482

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole sentence is in Masechet Brachot 60b:

> הנכנס לבית הכסא, אומר: התכבדו מכובדים קדושים משרתי עליון, תנו כבוד לאלהי ישראל, הרפו ממני עד שאכנס ואעשה רצוני ואבא אליכם.‏
>
> On entering a privy one should say: 'Be honoured, ye honoured and holy ones that minister to the Most High. Give honour to the God of Israel. **leave me till I enter** and do my needs, and return to you'.

1. Rashi explains that he says this to the angels who accompany him.
2. The Taz explains the fact that we don't say this anymore because we
       think that we are not sufficiently in the fear of G-d.
3. The Shaare Teshuva says that only very exceptional persons can say this and if a standard person says this it seems as over self esteem.
4. This statement said explicitely tha he is separating from angels **prior to entering**.

You can read more in the [Gemara](http://dtorah.com/otzar/shas_soncino.php?ms=Berachoth&df=60b)